# Approximating $3SAT$ by polynomials

Tags: lo.logic, real-analysis, polynomials

Given $3SAT$ formula $\phi$ in $n$ variables and a $\mu\in(0,1/2)$ what is the smallest degree of polynomial $f\in\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that for an $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\{0,1\}^n$ if $\phi(a_1,\dots,a_n)=1$ then $|f(a_1\pm\delta,\dots,a_n\pm\delta)|>\frac12$ and if $\phi(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$ then $|f(a_1\pm\delta,\dots,a_n\pm\delta)|<\frac12$ if $|\delta |<\mu$?

We know the degree cannot exceed $n$.

Comment: Probably $|\mu|<\delta$ at the end of the question should be $|\delta|<\mu$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Made modifications.